# get div inside fixed position parent div to 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have `div1` nested inside a fixed positioned parent div called `frame` and `div2` which has many rows of text. I want `div1` to be the width of the page(100%), but it is being resized to as far as the text goes. is there a way get it to `100%` and keep the `frame` div fixed. this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20bqrh4L/2/) demonstrates my problem. Thank you.

```css
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
}

#frame {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="div1">i should be as wide as the page</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <p>x</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can if you set #frame width to 100%, it cannot be any wider than it's parent without changing it's positioning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Css edit

```
#frame {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Anuresh just for info, you need to only use `right: 0;` or `width: 100%;` if you are using `position: fixed;` as long as your `left` is `0`

Comment: @weBer okay. 'left' will be zero by default, right ?

Comment: @Anuresh no I have never heard of it. Even if it is, `always play on safe side` new browsers are bringing new things day by day, we don't know what will mess up what on our page. SO ALWAYS PLAY ON SAFE SIDE Bro. :)

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you.

You could always use [**`vw`**](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) for getting the `#div1` to the page full width irrespective of its ***content*** or ***its parent's width*.**

> Go with `100vw` = 100% of the View Port Width

```css
body{margin:0px;}
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100vw;
  position:relative;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
}

#frame {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="div1">i should be as wide as the page</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <p>x</p>
</div>
```

One more thing if you want to be more specific about it you can also use **[`cal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** for clearing the border pixels.

> `calc(100vw - 2px)` = 100% of the View Port Width - border width

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(100vw - 2px);
  position: relative;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
}

#frame {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="div1">i should be as wide as the page</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <p>x</p>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting, i never knew about vw. it works, but causes horizontal scroll bar. +1

Comment: @user2014429 That's because your `<body>` has margin by default. you have to set it to `body{margin:0px;}` like I did in my fiddle. ;) and also take a look at `calc()` it may come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

`#div1` will be as big as it's **parent** in this case `#frame` that is what 100% means.

Solution 1. [Recomended] Set `#frame` size E.g. `width: 100%;`

Solution 2. Set `#div1` width based on your view port size E.g. `width: 100vw;`